# При отправке запроса получаю 403

Tags: c#, запрос

Сайт, которому нужно отправить `POST` запрос (или для начала хотя бы получить содержимое страницы) - http://e96774g6.beget.tech/

Открываю через браузер - всё ок, с другого устройства - всё ок, отправляю запрос через тестер - всё ок, отправляю запрос из приложения - получаю `403 forbidden`

В чём может быть проблема?

Код (пробовал и другой):

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
    response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
}

var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Возьмите сниффер, сравните успешный и неуспешный запросы. HTTP 403 это проблема авторизации, сервер по одной ему известной причине решил что вам нельзя отдавать страницу.

Comment: `client.GetAsync ` отправляет `GET` запрос

Comment: 1) Вы создаете новый экземпляр `HttpClient` на каждый запрос - [не надо так](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples), соответственно и `DefaultRequestHeaders` в этом случае нужно будет задать один раз. 2) `HttpResponseMessage` это `IDisposable`, используйте `using`, ну либо так как в ответе предложено.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja `403` - это "отказано в доступе", "не авторизован" - это `401` ([пруф](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status))

Comment: @aepot, "отказано в доступе" это и есть ошибка авторизации. Сервер знает кто ты, но тебе не разрешено это видеть. Authentication vs authorization: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-vs-authorization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно прикинуться браузером - задать заголовок UserAgent.

```
string url = "http://e96774g6.beget.tech/";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0");
    
    var s = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```