# Как получить "быстрый ответ" Google на C#?

Tags: c#, .net, парсер, anglesharp

У меня задача - получить "быстрый ответ" со страницы Google на C#.

Пример "быстрого ответа":

[image: Пример "быстрого ответа"]

Я обычно использую AngleSharp для парсинга на C#, но у меня элементарно не получается полностью загрузить страницу Google:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string page = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.google.com/search?q=что+такое+круг")
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как загрузить страницу, чтобы в HTML коде были теги, относящиеся к этому "быстрому ответу" (На самом деле я не сильно разбираюсь в данной теме, поэтому прошу о помощи)? Или вообще стоит отказаться от идеи парсинга страницы?

Comment: Как минимум, нужно притвориться браузером, указать заголовки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1147195/184217. Как максимум, выполнять JavaScript'ы.

Comment: Гугл хорошо защитил себя от ботов. Ищите API для этих задач, через парсинг HTML ничего не выйдет. В теории конечно можно обойти защиту, но это будет очень нелегко.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , спасибо большое, Ваш ответ действительно помог. Обязательно в заголовках указывать актуальную информацию про операционную систему (Windows 11) и браузер (Chrome)?

Comment: лучше всего генерировать случайные заголовки каждый запрос